# Декомпиляция DLL

Tags: dll, декомпиляция

Как можно декомпилировать любую DLL в обычный код. Какая программа самая лучшая?

Comment: Вы бы хоть указали, на чем dll-ка была реализована

Comment: В общем случае никак